# Can adding new ProtoInclude attribute be made to not break backwards compatibility

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

We have run into a backwards compatibility issue where we have added new subclass of a protobufed interface, but this means that this object cannot be opened in previous versions.

In general this is ok, all our deserialized objects are done so separately so failures to deserialize can't pull down everything else. Unfortunately this interface is serialized in a list, so the presence of a object of the new type in that class will cause the whole list to not be deserialized.

Is there a way to mark the class or the list in the **current** version so that the **old** version will simply omit those objects that can not be satisfied.

Just too be clear, we are wondering about modifying what we have on the *serializing* side of this problem.

A test to replicate the exception:

```
using System.IO;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace UnitTest.ProtoBuf
{

    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(1, typeof(ImplementorInV2))]
    internal interface IInterfaceV2
    {
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    internal interface IInterfaceV1
    {
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    internal class ImplementorInV2 : IInterfaceV2
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Member { get; set; }
    }

    [TestFixture, Category("Framework")]
    internal class ProtoIncludeAddedTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void BasicTest()
        {
            var a = new ImplementorInV2();
            a.Member = "bla bla";
            byte[] buffer;
            IInterfaceV1 aCopy;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, a);
                buffer = stream.ToArray();
            }
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                aCopy = Serializer.Deserialize<IInterfaceV1>(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: yes-ish; in your specific scenario - possibly not, basically. If this was class inheritance, it would deserialize *as far as it could* down the known inheritance chain, i.e. if you had

```
[ProtoContract]
class Foo {} // v1
```

and

```
[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Bar))]
class Foo {}
[ProtoContract]
class Bar : Foo {} // v2
```

and then serialized a `Bar` in v2, a v1 client would simply deserialize it as a `Foo` and ignore the unexpected data. However, the problem in your case is that *there is no default implementation* for an interface - it can't create anything. There *is* actually a way to specify the default type to create for lists etc, for exactly this reason, but by the time you've deployed that you might as well just deploy the v2 code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in moving moving forward then.

Comment: Do you have any links on specifying the default type to create for lists?